# Restore a single Mt Lion app

Tags: preview

Somehow, I don't know how or when, I deleted preview.app. Everything else is fine. What's the easiest way to get it back?

Comment: Perhaps it's still in the Trash? It may be in root's trash `/.Trashes`, not in yours, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Copy it from a backup or another Mac.
- Download an OS X installer from App Store, and use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com) to copy the application bundle.

  [image]
- Wait until 10.9 is released.
- Download an OS X installer from App Store and install it on a virtual machine with VMware Fusion, Parallels Desktop, or VirtualBox.
- [Do an upgrade install of OS X from the recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763).

Comment: Thanks. I used your suggestion #2 which worked beautifully. I had never tried using Pacifist!